# Concept of the slope

Tags: calculus, derivatives, soft-question, slope

Having difficulties understanding the concept of the slope:

Suppose we have $f(x)=x^2$, its derivative $f'(x)=2x$

At $x=10$, $f(x)=100$ and $f'(x)=20$. So the rate of change of the function at $(x,y)=(10,100)$ is $20$, but what does that mean? If we take $x+1=11$, we get: $f(11)=121$ and not $120$.

So what was the point of calculating the slope at (10,100)? What information did it provide us?

Comment: The *instantaneous* rate of change of $f$ at $x =10$ is $20$.

Comment: @littleO, Hi, could you elaborate on the definition of instantaneous rate of change? It just seems weird to me to talk about a "rate of change" if, as soon as we change points, we have a new "rate of change"

Comment: "Instantaneous rate of change" is not such a strange concept if you are used to looking at a car's speedometer. Imagine you start driving along a straight road and your speed increases steadily from $0$ to $25$ meters per second ( which is about 60 mph). Along the way, there was a single instant when the speedometer pointed at $20$ and you were going $20$ meters per second.  That is not so strange. And how far did you travel during the second after that single instant? Did you move exactly $20$ meters during that second? No, because you were still speeding up, so you moved a little further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it provided us with the slope at that exact point on the graph. Of course in this case the slope will change as soon as we move away from this point.

What can we do with the slope? We can for example see if that point on the graph is a possible local minima/maxima. If the slope is not equal to 0, there is no possibility for this to be the case, since we could move a bit up/down to find a higher/lower point. If we examine all cases where the slope is 0, we have a chance of finding our targets.

Another example would be the slope being acceleration of a particle in a physics model. Finding the acceleration at a point in time can allow us to derive other properties of the particle, such as force.

Answer (score 1):

The line through the two points $(10,100)$ and $(11,121)$ on the graph is called a secant line, and it's slope is $21$.

If you pick a point closer to $(10,100)$ than the point $(11,121)$ you will find that the resulting secant line will have slope closer to $20$.

In a way, you are "sneaking up" on the slope of the tangent line by approaching it with a sequence of secant lines.

The slope of the tangent line is the limit of the slopes of the secant lines.